# C# DataGrid linking to List of Objects with properties

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, datagridview, datagrid

I have a datagridview and a list of objects... I am trying to set the datasource of the grid to this list, but somehow the datagridview always turns up empty. Although, when I debug, the datasource property of the datagridview is populated by a list of my objects

Here is what I got how my object looks like:

```
 public class TextIFileObject
    {
        public string name;
        public long totalChars;
        public bool bearbeitet;
        public string path; ....}
```

I populate the list like this:

```
    public BindingList<TextIFileObject> allDetectedFiles = new BindingList<TextIFileObject>();
FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt");
                foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
                {
                    TextIFileObject tmp = new TextIFileObject(file);
                    allDetectedFiles.Add(tmp);

                }
```

and finally I set the source of the datagrid like this:

```
 dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dataGridView1.AutoSize = true;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = allDetectedFiles;
```

I have draged the datagridview out on the form from the toolbox (if somehow that is relevant!)

and here is how my form looks like: (the datagrid is simply empty! )

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a small piece of Code to show it via example:

https://github.com/kelrien/DotNetExampleDataBinding

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I was not using publicly visible getters!
something like this:

```
public class TextIFileObject
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public long totalChars{ get; set; }
        public bool bearbeitet{ get; set; }
        public string path; ....}
```